# IndexPathForCell returning incorrect indexpath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get information out of a UITextField inside my tableViewCells. My viewcontroller is the delegate of each of my cells, each of which is a textfield delegate. In textfieldDidEndEditing, I call a delegate method in my view controller that is supposed to determine which cell it is and store the information in the cell's textfield. However, my indexPathForCell is not corresponding to the one in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Here is my code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell?
        switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
        case (0,0):
            cell = self.informationCell(withInstructions: "First name", andAnswer: employee.first_name!)
            break
        case (0,1):
            cell = self.informationCell(withInstructions: "Last name", andAnswer: employee.last_name!)
            break
        case (0,2):
            cell = self.informationCell(withInstructions: "Job title", andAnswer: employee.job_title!)
            break
        case (1,0):
            cell = self.informationCell(withInstructions: "Company name", andAnswer: employee.company_name!)
            break
        case (1,1):
            cell = self.informationCell(withInstructions: "Target hours per week", andAnswer: employee.hours_per_week == 0 ? "" : "\(employee.hours_per_week!)")
            break
        case (1,2):
            cell = self.informationCell(withInstructions: "Wage per hour", andAnswer: employee.wage_per_hour! == 0 ? "" : "\(employee.wage_per_hour!)")
            break
        default: assert(false, "Too many rows?")
        return cell!
   }
```

and where I retrieve the information:

```
func informationTextDidChange(sender: InformationEnterBaseCell) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
    print((indexPath!.section, indexPath!.row))
    switch (indexPath!.section, indexPath!.row) {
    case (0,0):
        self.employee.first_name = sender.textfield.text
        break
    case (0,1):
        self.employee.last_name = sender.textfield.text
        break
    case (0,2):
        self.employee.job_title = sender.textfield.text
        break
    case (1,0):
        self.employee.company_name = sender.textfield.text
        break
    case (1,1):
        if let hours = Double(sender.textfield.text!) {
            self.employee.hours_per_week = hours
        }
        break
    case (1,2):
        if let wage = Double(sender.textfield.text!) {
            self.employee.wage_per_hour = wage
        }
        break
    default: assert(false, "Too many rows?")
    }
}
```

My problem is that the tuplets of (section, row) no longer correspond. I am wondering why this is and how I can fix it or approach this better. I know cells are reused, but I thought that the indexPath's row and section stayed the same. Thank you for any help.

Edit:

I set the delegate in this function:

```
private func informationCell(withInstructions instructions: String, andAnswer answer: String) -> InformationEnterBaseCell {
        let cell = InformationEnterBaseCell()
        cell.configureWithInstructions(instructions, andAnswer: answer)
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Is that the complete `cellForRowAt` function? If so, you never return the cell. How/Where are you setting your view controller as the delegate of your cells? (It is not clear from your code). Also, switch statements do not need the keyword `break` in swift, see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: You may want to consider using `dequeueReusableCell` in `cellForRowAt` and just casting the result  as your custom class. Then, of course, setting the delegate and the running your `cell.configureWithInstructions` inside the switch.

Comment: Rather than relying on the indexPath, I would add an enum which defines each of your text fields and store that as a property of your custom cell.